# NPC in Array path

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, coordinates

I am to create a game to work in the terminal(no GUI), I am able to move my character throughout the array using keys, now I need to create NPCs(Hunters) that will spawn at 12,12 point of the array, and move to 0,0 with a random pre-defined path ( it is essential that all paths within 12x12 array are used) Could anyone flash some light on this please?

```
package hunters;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*; 
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Hunters {
    private static int score;
    private static String player = "P";
    private static String move;
    private static   String emptyfield = "X";
    private static   String [][]a2 = new String [12][12];
    private static int pr,pc;
    private static String hunter = "H";
    private static int hr=11,hc=11;

    public static void paint_board(){

        for (int r = 0 ; r < a2.length; r++){
            for (int c= 0; c <a2[r].length; c++){
                a2 [r][c] = emptyfield;
                a2[pr][pc] = player;
                a2[hr][hc]= hunter;
                System.out.print(" "+a2[r][c]);
            }
            System.out.println(""); 
        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        score = 0;

        paint_board();
        do{
            ystem.out.println("Input your move");
            move = in.nextLine();
            if (move.equalsIgnoreCase("w")){
             //move up
               pr = pr -1;
                //repaint
               paint_board();
                //check for collision
                //check for health

            }else if(move.equalsIgnoreCase("s")){
                //move down
                pr = pr +1;
                 for (int i = 0; i <20; i++) System.out.println();
                //repaint
                paint_board();
                  //check for collision
                //check for health

            }else if(move.equalsIgnoreCase("d")){
                //move right
                pc = pc +1;
                //repaint
                paint_board();
                  //check for collision
                //check for health

            }else if(move.equalsIgnoreCase("a")){
                //move left
                pc = pc -1;
               for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) System.out.println("");
                //repaint
                paint_board();
                  //check for collision
                //check for health

            }
        }while(score !=5);
    }   
}
```

Comment: You really should narrow down your problem. This forum is not for letting others do your work, but for letting others help you with specific programming related questions. Please read the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Could your hunters move backward?

Comment: Where do I start with setting up NPC random movement from 12,12 to 0,0? NPC is a letter "H" in the 12x12 array.

Comment: No, they can not move backwards.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use breadth-first search (BFS).

This gives you a map showing how many steps it takes at least to get to every free field on your map from (12,12).

Then you can make your NPCs move backward field by field backward from (0,0) in the direction of one of the fields with the greatest number that is smaller than that of the field they're currently standing on, based on a random desicion.

This way, you will get one of the shortest paths, which you then just have to let your NPCs walk along.

Then you can add further randomization to make them take a detour now and then if you want more unpredictable behavior - i.e. make them sometimes choose a non-optimal next field, based on a random decision.

And then go and spend some time on one of the many game development blogs out there - i.e. google

game development breadth-first

game development a-star

(a-star is a more sophsticated path-finding algorithm)

This way you should be able learn a lot about these things - wikipedia articles are sometimes rather difficult to understand without the necessary mathematical background, hence my suggestion of looking for game development specific content.